# Angular 2 / Bootstrap list-group select item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have bootstrap `list-group`, and I want to make one item selected with a darker background via a class that will toggle for the selected item. What is the best way to have one item selected after a selection?

```
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="media" *ngFor="let group of _groups">
    <div class="group-title">{{group.groupTitle}}</div>
    <div (click)="setSelectedItem($event, widget)" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let widget of group.widgets">
      {{widget.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="media" *ngFor="let group of _groups">
    <div class="group-title">{{group.groupTitle}}</div>
    <div (click)="setSelectedItem(widget)"
      [ngClass]="[(_selectedWidget == widget) ? 'selected' : '']"
      class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let widget of group.widgets">
      {{widget.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngClass` e.g. `[ngClass]="{'selected':widget.selected}"`

```
<div (click)="setSelectedItem($event, widget)" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let widget of group.widgets" [ngClass]="{'selected':widget.selected}">
...
```

I'm assuming `setSelectedItem()` will set `widget.selected = true`.

You'll need to add a selected class to your stylesheet.

Comment: This got me in the right direction, but you forgot the square brackets around ngClass.